# Is there a way to make my sprite jump without a platform?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

Right now my player sprite can move right or left. I have set up gravity for my player and as expected it drops out of the screen. I have read many documentation on how to make sprites jump. However, they all explain it with platforms used as bases where the sprite can land and move around on. In order to do that they load platform images or create some with pygame. But before writing much code I had already drawn a background for my game which included ground. So I don't wish to create new platforms for my game (for now). Is there a way to make my sprite jump in my program without using platforms? A thought of mine would be to set the "platform" as a certain line on my y-axis. But how do I do that? I'm open to any ideas. Thanks beforehand. My code is separated into 3 files: a main.py, a settings.py and a Sprite1.py. Here's main.py:

```
import pygame
import os
import sys
import time
from pygame import mixer
from Sprite1 import *
from settings import *

'''
Setup
'''
pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.mixer.music.load('.\\sounds\\Fairy.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player(all_sprites)


player.rect.x = 50
player.rect.y = 500




showStartScreen(surface)

'''
Main loop
'''

main = True



while main == True:

    background = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('images', 'Bg.png'))
    surface.blit(background, (0,0))



    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
            main = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                player.control(-steps,0)

            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                player.control(steps,0)

            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                player.jump()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                player.control(steps,0)

            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                player.control(-steps,0)

            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                player.jump_cut()

    dt = clock.tick(60) / 1000
    all_sprites.update(dt)
    player.update(dt)
    all_sprites.draw(surface) #refresh player position
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Here is settings.py:

```
import pygame

width = 960
height = 720
fps = 40        # frame rate
pygame.display.set_caption('B.S.G.')
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
PLAYER_ACC = 0.5
PLAYER_FRICTION = -0.12
PLAYER_GRAV = 0.8
PLAYER_JUMP = 20
PLAYER_LAYER = 2
PLATFORM_LAYER = 1
RED = (255, 0, 0)

steps = 10      # how fast to move
```

And here's Sprite1.py:

```
import pygame
import sys
import os
import time
from pygame import mixer
from pygame.locals import *
from settings import *
vec = pygame.math.Vector2

def showStartScreen(surface):
    show = True
    while (show == True):
        background = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('images', 'Starting_scr.png'))
        # rect = surface.get_rect()
        surface.blit(background, (0,0))
        pygame.display.flip()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                show = False

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, all_sprites):
        self._layer = PLAYER_LAYER
        #self.groups = game.all_sprites
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        #self.game = game
        self.movex = 0
        self.movey = 0
        self.frame = 0
        self.health = 10
        self.jumping = False
        self.images = []
        self.imagesleft = []
        self.imagesright = []
        self.direction = "right"
        self.alpha = (0,0,0)
        self.ani = 4 # animation cycles
        self.all_sprites = all_sprites
        self.add(self.all_sprites)
        self.bullet_timer = .1
        self.pos = vec(40, height - 100)
        self.vel = vec(0, 0)
        self.acc = vec(0, 0)

        for i in range(1,5):
            img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('images','hero' + str(i) + '.png')).convert()
            img.convert_alpha()
            img.set_colorkey(self.alpha)
            self.imagesright.append(img)
            self.image = self.imagesright[0]
            self.rect  = self.image.get_rect()

        for i in range(1,5):
            img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('images','hero' + str(i) + '.png')).convert()
            img = pygame.transform.flip(img, True, False)
            img.convert_alpha()
            img.set_colorkey(self.alpha)
            self.imagesleft.append(img)
            self.image = self.imagesleft[0]
            self.rect  = self.image.get_rect()

    def control(self,x,y):
        '''
        control player movement
        '''
        self.movex += x
        self.movey -= y

    def jump_cut(self):
        if self.jumping:
            if self.vel.y < -3:
                #self.rect.y += 100
                self.vel.y = -3
                #self.jumping = False
                print(self.vel.y)

    def jump(self):
        # jump only if standing on a platform
        #self.rect.y += 20
        #hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.platforms, False)
        #self.rect.y -= 100
        if self.rect.y == 500 and not self.jumping:
            #self.game.jump_sound.play()
            self.jumping = True
            self.vel.y = -PLAYER_JUMP
            print(self.rect.y)

    def update(self, dt):
        '''
        Update sprite position
        '''
        self.rect.x = self.rect.x + self.movex
        self.rect.y = self.rect.y + self.movey

        self.acc = vec(0, PLAYER_GRAV)

        # apply friction
        self.acc.x += self.vel.x * PLAYER_FRICTION
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.acc.x = -PLAYER_ACC
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.acc.x = PLAYER_ACC
        # equations of motion
        self.vel += self.acc
        if abs(self.vel.x) < 0.1:
            self.vel.x = 0
        self.pos += self.vel + 0.5 * self.acc
        # wrap around the sides of the screen
        if self.pos.x > width + self.rect.width / 2:
            self.pos.x = 0 - self.rect.width / 2
        if self.pos.x < 0 - self.rect.width / 2:
            self.pos.x = width + self.rect.width / 2

        self.rect.midbottom = self.pos

        # moving left
        if self.movex < 0:
            self.frame += 1
            if self.frame > 3*self.ani:
                self.frame = 0
            self.image = self.imagesleft[self.frame//self.ani]
            self.direction = "left"

        # moving right
        if self.movex > 0:
            self.frame += 1
            if self.frame > 3*self.ani:
                self.frame = 0
            self.image = self.imagesright[self.frame//self.ani]
            self.direction = "right"

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            self.bullet_timer -= dt  # Subtract the time since the last tick.

        if self.bullet_timer <= 0:
            self.bullet_timer = 100  # Bullet ready.
            if keys:  # Left mouse button.
                # Create a new bullet instance and add it to the groups.
                if self.direction == "right":
                    Bullet([self.rect.x + self.image.get_width(), self.rect.y + self.image.get_height()/2], self.direction, self.all_sprites)
                else:
                    Bullet([self.rect.x, self.rect.y + self.image.get_height()/2], self.direction, self.all_sprites)
                self.bullet_timer = .1  # Reset the timer.



class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    IMAGE = None
    FLIPPED_IMAGE = None

    def __init__(self, pos, direction, *sprite_groups):
        super().__init__(*sprite_groups)

        if not Bullet.IMAGE:
            Bullet.IMAGE = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('images','fireball.png'))
            Bullet.FLIPPED_IMAGE = pygame.transform.flip(Bullet.IMAGE, True, False)

        if direction == "right":
            self.vel = pygame.math.Vector2(750, 0)
            self.image = Bullet.IMAGE
        else:
            self.vel = pygame.math.Vector2(-750, 0)
            self.image = Bullet.FLIPPED_IMAGE

        self.pos = pygame.math.Vector2(pos)
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)

    def update(self, dt):
        # Add the velocity to the position vector to move the sprite
        self.pos += self.vel * dt
        self.rect.center = self.pos  # Update the rect pos.
        if not pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect().colliderect(self.rect):
            self.kill()
```

Comment: So your existing implementation of `jump()` does not work?

Comment: Thank you for your time but I figured it out in the end!

Comment: That's always the best outcome :D !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding a way to make it work just as how I wished it would!
I firstly wrote these variables to my settings.py:

```
isJump = False
jumpCount = 10
```

I added this part of code to my main.py main loop after the KEYDOWN and KEYUP:

```
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if not(isJump):
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            isJump = True
    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            player.rect.y -= (jumpCount * abs(jumpCount)) * 1
            jumpCount -= 2
        else:
            jumpCount = 10
            isJump = False
```

I learned all of this on this website: https://techwithtim.net/tutorials/game-development-with-python/pygame-tutorial/jumping/